# How to prevent specific output to Eclipse Console via IPatternMatchListenerDelegate?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, console

According to the Eclipse documentation it's pretty easy to capture specific output from the Eclipse console via  [IPatternMatchListenerDelegate](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_console_consolePatternMatchListeners.html):

- Create an extension point
- Write a suitable **regex** (what you want to capture)
- Implement **IPatternMatchListenerDelegate** - **matchFound** event will be fired when output of the console matches regular expression

But, is it possible to prevent output of the specific messages? for instance, all messages that starts with *INFO*.

Comment: I don't see anything to stop output in that listener.

Comment: ^Sure, that's why I'm asking :)